# How can I create a full screen page from a persistent notification on lockscreen in my Android app?

Tags: java, kotlin, notifications, foreground-service

when i installed an android app it added a persistent notification to my tray and then every time i turn off and turn back on my device it shows a full screen page that has links on it now. how did they make that notification show as a full screen thing on my device when i go to my lock screen?

you can see it in the picture [it appears when a user wakes his phone up full without "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" permission, they say it is done by using these "Notification runtime permission  |  Android Developers

Using a media session  |  Android Developers "](https://i.stack.imgur.com/abjLF.png)

I tried "SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW" but this is not what I want i need to achieve this without asking for any permission